# can't define a particular function

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to fix a bug in my program, but I have no idea how to even search for it. this function should take the coordinates that I give it and make a rectangle with coordinates multiplied by 10x, the origin being in the center, and the coordinates being at the center of the rectangle, but I'm getting a "invalid syntax" on these exact lines. please help!

```
def drawrect(screen, (r, g, b), (x, y, w, h)):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (r, g, b), (((width / 2) - w) * (x * 10), ((height / 2) - h) * (y * 10), w, h))
```

Comment: The ability to define tuples of parameters like that was present in Python 2.x only.  You'd have to declare the function as `drawrect(screen, rgb, xywh)` now, then do `x, y, w, h = xywh` to manually unpack that parameter.  (You don't need to unpack `rgb`, since you're passing it on as a complete unit.)

Comment: You can't unpack function argument that way. you should unpack it in function body.

Comment: @jasonharper so I changed it to `def drawrect(screen, rgb, xywh):
    x, y, w, h = xywh
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (r, g, b), (((width / 2) - w) * (x * 10), ((height / 2) - h) * (y * 10), w, h))` but I get "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." maybe its because im calling it like `drawrect(screen, 255,255,255, position[0],position[1],10,10)` is this right?

Comment: Nothing in that code has the slightest thing to do with network connections, which is what the error is about.  Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @jasonharper I fixed the connection problem, but I couldnt get my code to work. eventually I settled on using the main pygame rect draw function, but I would run the position parameters through a function that would change them to the coordinates I want. thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run with the answers, but they were not working so I came up with a new function that changes each number individually. the additional variable is so that you can make certain things spawn with the center at the given coordinates and not the corner.

```
def place(Input, axis, additional):
return ((axis / 2) - (Input / 2) * 10) - additional
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to call them like a list. so for example instead of r, g, and b,
use rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]. and instead of x, y, w, h. use xywh[0], xywh[1], xywh[2], and xywh[3]. and lastly make sure that when ever you call your function that rgb and xywh are lists in case you aren't already,

example:

1 def drawrect(screen, rgb, xywh):pygame.draw.rect(screen, (rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]), (((width / 2) - xywh[2]) * (xywh[0] * 10), ((height / 2) - xywh[3]) * (xywh[1] * 10), xywh[2], xywh[3]))

2 xywh = [25,14,235,122]

3 rbg = [255,255,255]

4 drawrect(screen, rgb, xywh)

I hope that works for you!

Comment: thanks, but I changed my idea later and instead went with a different function that changes each number individually. this may be helpful for future projects though, so take my updoot.